# Angular 5 | ReactiveForm with ControlValueAccessor | onChange is not triggered

Tags: angular, angular5, onchange, angular-reactive-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I have a custom ControlValueAccessor which simply appends a currency symbol on an input.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-currency-input',
  templateUrl: './currency-input.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./currency-input.component.scss'],
  providers: [
    CurrencyPipe,
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CurrencyInputComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class CurrencyInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() class = '';

  currencyValue: string;

  onChange: (value: number) => void;
  onTouched: () => void;

  constructor(
    private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe
  ) { }

  parseToNumber(currencyString: string) {
    this.onChange(this.currencyPipe.parse(currencyString));
  }

  transformToCurrencyString(value: number): string {
    return this.currencyPipe.transform(value);
  }

  writeValue(value: number): void {
    if (value !== undefined) {
      this.currencyValue = this.transformToCurrencyString(value);
    }
  }

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

}
```

The `CurrencyPipe` just parses the string to number and transforms a number to a currency string (with localized decimal seperator and currency symbol).

When I try to use ReactiveForms like this:

```html
<app-currency-input
  name="amount"
  class="value-box"
  formControlName="amount"
  required
></app-currency-input>
```

... then `onChange()` is not triggered on manual input.

I have a workaround, where I subscribe to the `valueChanges` of the control and then do a

```js
control.patchValue(newValue, { emitModelToViewChange: true })
```

... which successfully triggers the `onChange` for the ControlValueAccessor. *(A `patchValue` without options would do the same, because `true` is the default value for this option. I just wanted to point out the culprit here.)*

But I would love to use an inbuilt solution which does not resolve in additional needed checks and at least two valueChanges.

---

A simplified Plunker to try it out: https://embed.plnkr.co/c4YMw87FiZMpN5Gr8w1f/
See the commented out code in `src/app.ts`.

Comment: `onChange: (value: number) => console.log("value change")` does not get called?

Comment: please post `./currency-input.component.html`

Comment: what is <app-currency-input>? Ideally you want to just use a normal form field here. Traditionally you can only use formControlName on a normal form field unless you have imported a library.

Comment: @ForestG Correct, it does not get called unless I do this mentioned workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```js
import { Component, Input, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { CurrencyPipe, } from '@angular/common';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, FormControl, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';

@Component({
  selector: 'currency-input',
  template: `<input [formControl]="formControl" (blur)="onTouched()"/>`,
  styles: [`h1 { font-family: Lato; }`],
  providers: [
    CurrencyPipe,
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => CurrencyInputComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class CurrencyInputComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
  constructor(private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe) { }

  private onChange: Function;
  private onTouched: Function;

  formControl = new FormControl('');
  subscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscription = this.formControl.valueChanges
      .subscribe((v) => {
        this.onChange && this.onChange(this.transform(v));
      })
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
   this.subscription.unsubscribe();
  }

  writeValue(val) {
    this.formControl.setValue(this.transform(val), { emitEvent: false });
  }

  registerOnChange(fn) {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn) {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }

  private transform(val: string) {
    return this.currencyPipe.transform(val, 'USD')
  }
}
```

Please note that I'm using the `ReactiveFormsModule` so you need to import it in your module.

[Live demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a9sxm6)

Comment: It did not work. No currency symbol was added. But I got an JS-Error: `Maximum call stack size exceeded`. Calling `this.onChange()` will result in `valueChanges` event of the formControl to get fired.

Comment: Check out my edit. Also make sure to open the live demo.

Comment: I will accept this as the correct answer, since it pointed me in the correct direction. After my comment I changed the subscription to `.subscribe(value => this.writeValue(value))` which works as expected.

Comment: Glad you figured it out. Thanks :)

Comment: Live demo work, but transformed value is rendered as text after input. Have same problem with stackoverflow on setValue / patchValue. As I see, have functional currency  masked control is BRUTAL problem. All samples about this is not usable in real world, or able display formatted value only.

Comment: you saved my day! tnx