# how to create existing component multiple times on button click - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-components

I'm trying to create a component several times on a button click. The button is in the parent component and when the click "Add more" it will create the child component as many times as they click "Add more". By default there's only one child component showing then when we click on the button the same child component will be added after the existing one.

**how to create existing child component multiple times on button click?**

**Should I use component Factory or just a plain forLoop?**

**HTML -Child component**

```
<input type="text />
```

**HTML -Parent component**

```
<child-component #childCom></child-component>

<button (click)="addMore()">Add more</button>
```

**TS**

```
@ViewChild('childCom') childCom: ElementRef;

addMore(){
     console.log("child component");
}
```

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: @LazarLjubenović updated my question. but the question is how to create existing component multiple times on button click?

Comment: Follow the tutorial on `*ngFor`: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2

Comment: @David Walschots I don't think I was clear with my question or you didn't understand it. I think I need  to use componentFactory? Or how are you adding the child component to the array?  Or can I important the component to the parent and added to the array with out component Factory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The idea

Use a for loop for display a component multiple times.

## The array

Each time you want to add a new item, we'll add another item into the array (for example the array could be `0`, `1`, `2` or you could keep some state there -- this depends on your app).

```
public items = []

public add () {
  this.items = [...this.items, this.items.length]
}
```

## The template

We call the `add` method from the template when you click a button.

```
<button (click)="add()">Add</button>
```

And we iterate over the array and create the component multiple times.

```
<child-component *ngFor="let item of items"></child-component>
```

## The flow

When the user clicks the button, method `add` is called. This makes the length of the array longer by one. `ngFor` notices this and renders another item.

Comment: But how would his work if angular is AOT? and im recreating the component again

Comment: It works perfectly fine with AOT. AOT compilation refers to compiling templates to JavaScript during build-time instead of during execution. I suggest you not worry about AOT for a while, there's a rather interesting journey ahead of you: https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt1

Comment: I don't think I was clear with my question or you didn't understand it. I think I need  to use componentFactory? Or how are you adding the child component to the array?  Or can I important the component to the parent and added to the array with out component Factory.

Comment: I don't understand what's the issue. Is my solution not doing what you asked for? You do **not** need to use componentFactory. I'm not adding a child component to the array, I'm adding a random number. The component is rendered via a template. You asked: "create a component several times on a button click". If you have a different question, please open a new one.

Comment: @PatricioVargas - The only thing missing from this answer may be a stackblitz to show you that it does work and that you don't need to use a component factory.

Comment: it does work. I upvote the answer.  here's the working stackbliz. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fzzulg. what's better to use in this situations? this or componentFactory? @LazarLjubenović

Comment: @ConnorsFan see my comment above

Comment: @PatricioVargas using `*ngFor` is simpler than using `componentFactory`. I'd go for simplicity :-).

Comment: It makes no sense to use dynamic factories for just looping over the same component over and over.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović haha that makes sense. How would I go to access the values entered in each dynamic input with 2 way binding?

Comment: You have them with you. If you've passed them via an input, you don't need to query them -- they're with you, in that component.

Comment: @LazarLjubenović :but this approach has an issue . If i have a form inside a component. It is taking same value in all multiplied components. Can you throw some light on this

Answer (score 1):

Use [ComponentFactoryResolver](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) for this

Add `ng-template` into your HTML page where you want to generate dynamic component

```
<child-component #childCom></child-component>
<ng-template #container></ng-template>
```

then in your component.ts

```
@ViewChild('container', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;
input = InputComponent;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {

  }
```

**`InputComponent` is child-component according to your code**

```
add() {
    const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.input);
    const component = this.container.createComponent(componentFactory);
  }
```

and don't forget to bootstrap your child-component in `NgModule`

```
bootstrap: [AppComponent], entryComponents: [InputComponent]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! this is exactly what I needed

Comment: How would I go to access the values entered in each dynamic component with 2 way binding?

Comment: I'm not sure about how to add `ngModel` to dynamic generated component, but for custom component, you'll need to implement `ControlValueAccessor` into your custom component. This is useful link  https://stackoverflow.com/a/49856272/1203961

Comment: You've `const component` and you've all access over your custom component. `const component` have `instance` property.